# Is there any penalty for failing to cross the Gauntlet?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, werewolf-the-forsaken-2e

If you attempt to cross the Gauntlet (in either direction) and fail the die roll, do you suffer any penalties (beyond staying on your current side of the Gauntlet, obviously). Our Storyteller recalls a penalty in W:tF 1e, but we have not found any mention of one in the 2e rule book.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Crossing the Gauntlet ("Reaching") is described on pages 100-101 of W:tF 2e. There is no penalty specific to a failed attempt to reach.

Note, however, that successive attempts can impose a cumulative -1 penalty to the roll if "time is short and the situation is tense" (W:tF 2e, page 162).

Comment: In general in nWoD (and I think they made this clearer in 2e). Any time you fail a roll to do a task, future attempts at that task during the same scene (i.e. retries) are made at -1 die. However, in 2e I know there are several rolls which explicitly do not apply that penalty.  Can you clarify your answer as to if it is one that explictly does not; or if you mean "there is only the normal penalty on retries, and no additional effects."